# What is oauth_token_secret in Twitter OAuth

Tags: twitter, oauth

When I get an access token from Twitter I get something like the following:

```
oauth_token=14410002-F5Bi8hMpQbXamM8MBBw8zw2LYIBL4FEBvxLZfaSwX&oauth_token_secret=K8QNvDcC2f9qtGU8tfa75exwLZ2Sc1jeHrThnk6Co&user_id=14410002&screen_name=blueonion
```

What is the oauth_token_secret? Is that what is used to sign protected requests or is the consumer_key still used.

Comment: I found the specification and read it dutifully. I missed the part oauth_token_secret in part because the spec refers to it as "Token Secret". Your implication that I didn't try hard enough before asking is unwarranted and not appropriate here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short answer is: The `oauth_token` and the `oauth_token_secret` both make up the Request token which is used to sign requests.

Here are some resources which might help:

- [the OAuth specification](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/) (esp. section 6)
- [Twitter Single-user OAuth with Examples](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples)
- [The terminology part of the OAuth guide](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/terminology/)

This is not the consumer key. The consumer key is only used for identifying the consumer (= the code which calls Twitter) while the Request Token is bound to the user. The Request Token consists then of a public and a secret part which are both used for signing the request as explained in the specification in section 9.

But you probably want to use one of the libraries and have a look at the examples.

Comment: Sure enough, staring me right in the face in section 9.2. I kept "seeing" Consumer Secret and skipped right over the Token Secret. The OAuth specification is a pretty easy read and I still managed to skip past it. Thanks.

As an aside, I discovered that you don't need the token_secret to get an access token in twitter. Probably a bug and it's what caused my confusion in the first place I suspect.

Answer (score 10):

this is actually a really good question because twitter appears to have broken the oauth 1.0 standard on this requirement. i found out by accident that if you omit the oauth_token_secret from the signing key, ie.

```
$signing_key = encode_rfc3986($consumer_secret).'&';
```

instead of

```
$signing_key = encode_rfc3986($consumer_secret).'&'.encode_rfc3986($oauth_token_secret);
```

when requesting the access token, both will work just the same for twitter.

on my website i developed twitter oauth before i developed any other oauth 1.0 service provider authentication and i couldnt figure out why an oauth_token_secret was even needed. once i tried the same code out on yahoo and linkedin i had a nasty shock since  the same code that worked for twitter did not work on the other service providers (ie i was using the first snippet above when i should have been using the second snippet)

Comment: Hey, tested. Still the case ! ;) Did you report it to twitter somewhen ?